# Regex in Exchange transport rule

Tags: exchange-2010, regex

We are receiving external emails with invalid characters in the emails address which is causing issues for applications linked to the mailboxes.

The receipient addresses contain single quotes ('name@domain.com') or a trailing period (name@domain.com.)

I was wondering is it possible to set a regular expression on the transport rule to filter for these emails and send it to the correct address ie name@domain.com. As there are multiple mailboxes, I don't want to create a rule for each mailbox.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks